# How many objects have been constructed while calling a function in C++

Tags: c++

I write a program to test how many objects will be constructed during the program's lifecycle, like this:

```
class T
{
public:
    virtual ~T() {cout << "dtor" << endl;}
};

const T* func() 
{
    T objinfunc;
    return &objinfunc;
}
int main() 
{
    T objinmain = *func();
    return 0;
}
```

I expect it would print "dtor" three times for destructing three objects such as objinfunc, return object and objinmain, but it prints two "dtor" in the end.

I confuse with the result.

Comment: You have undefined behaviour, so the question is moot. You are returning a pointer to a function's local variable.

Comment: Aside from the undefined behaviour, you're returning a pointer, not a class instance.  So no ctor/dtor involved there.

Comment: You'll probably be even more confused when you find that by fixing the undefined behavior (return the object by value), your destructor calls will likely go down to 1, instead of up to 3 like you expect.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley yep - copy elision

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're returning the address of a local here:

```
const T* func() 
{
    T objinfunc;
    return &objinfunc;
}
```

This yields Undefined Behavior.  `objinfunc` has been destroyed by the time the function returns, and you're taking the address of something that no longer exists.

Aside from this, you construct two instances of the object:  one in `func`, and another one in `main` (at least you try to).

Answer (score 0):

Apart from your code not having defined behavior, two times "dtor" is correct as you are returning a pointer to `T` in `func`. Your third object (return object) isn't really an object as it is just a pointer which will eventually point to deallocated memory.